# Start Workflow by column without Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-server, column

I got the following issue.

First of all, im not allowed to use SharePoint Designer.

i'm working with SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010.

A column named "Airbase" gets his data from a dropdown list in InfoPath(As example; Amsterdam - Eindhoven - Rotterdam )

My question is;
Is it possible to have 3 different workflows and start each of them when the required data is filled in the colomn (For example, When someone adds a new infopath file with "Amsterdam" as airbase , the workflow Amsterdam has to start. And when someone adds a infopath file with "Eindhoven" as airbase, the workflow Eindhoven has to start.)

Thanks in advance , and sorry for my English (its not my native language :/ )

Grrtz

Comment: Can't you create a single workflow on the list and then depending on what is chosen in the column "Airbase" the workflow will execute the related tasks. (Conditional statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use SharePoint Designer, I take it you will also not be using custom workflows created with Visual Studio. Is that correct?

In that case, there is not much you can do. You cannot create a workflow from the browser interface.

If you COULD use SharePoint Designer, you would only need one workflow. The workflow can evaluate the "Airbase" column and do different things depending on the value of the field, like ( in pseudo-code)

```
If Airbase equals Amsterdam
    do this

If Airbase equals Eindhoven
    do that

If Airbase equals Rotterdam
    do something different
```